# LINQ query to update property of a list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert the following code to linq:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < List.Count;i++ )
                {
                    List[i].IsActive = false;
                    if(List[i].TestList != null)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0;j<List[i].TestList.Count;j++)
                        {
                            List[i].TestList[j].IsActive = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I tried the following query :

```
(from s in List select s).ToList().ForEach((s) =>
                        {
                            s.IsActive = false;
                            (from t in s.TestList where t != null select t).ToList().ForEach((t) =>
                                {
                                    t.IsActive = false;
                                });
                        });
```

But i get an error when TestList is null in the list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `(from t in s.TestList where t == null select t)` this collect all items where t is `null`. Maybe `(from t in s.TestList where t != null select t)`

Comment: My mistake, it is t!=null i typed it wrong. However, I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original(no LINQ) code is worked.
Then you missed one line, which check for null of TestList before iterating items

```
(from s in List select s).ToList().ForEach((s) =>
    {
        s.IsActive = false;
        if(s.TestList != null) //This check of TestList was missing
            (from t in s.TestList where t != null select t).ToList().ForEach((t) =>
                        {
                                    t.IsActive = false;
                        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting lists that are null

```
where t == null
```

Should the condition be

```
where t != null
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach. No need to check for null.

```
 s.ForEach((x)=>
    {
        x.IsActive  = false;
        x.TestList.Foreach((t)=>{t.IsActive = false});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an inner loop since it looks like you're deactivating all nested `TestList` items. You can just have two separate loops:

```
foreach(var item in List)
   item.IsActive = false;

foreach(var item in List.Where(x => x.TestList != null).SelectMany(x => x.TestList))
   item.IsActive = false;
```

Note that `SelectMany` "flattens" the inner lists into a single `IEnumerable<T>`.